# Error in UseMethod("docvars") : no applicable method for 'docvars' applied to an object of class "c('corpus', 'character')"

Tags: r

I'm trying to use docvars() because I want to use Seeded LDA package in R.
but I had a problem and I can't search the way to fix this error.

First, I made corpus like this.

```
combined_df %>% 
+   corpus(text_field = "text2") -> c_corp
```

and the result is like this.

```
c_corp %>% glimpse()
 'corpus' Named chr [1:965] ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:965] "text1" "text2" "text3" "text4" ...
 - attr(*, "docvars")='data.frame': 965 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ docname_: chr [1:965] "text1" "text2" "text3" "text4" ...
  ..$ docid_  : Factor w/ 965 levels "text1","text2",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ segid_  : int [1:965] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ ID      : Factor w/ 965 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ text    : chr [1:965] | __truncated__ ...
 - attr(*, "meta")=List of 3
  ..$ system:List of 6
  .. ..$ package-version:Classes 'package_version', 'numeric_version'  hidden list of 1
  .. ..$ r-version      :Classes 'R_system_version', 'package_version', 'numeric_version'  hidden list of 1
  .. ..$ system         : Named chr [1:3] "Linux" "x86_64" "r1373953"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "sysname" "machine" "user"
  .. ..$ directory      : chr "/cloud/project"
  .. ..$ created        : Date[1:1], format:  ...
  .. ..$ source         : chr "data.frame"
  ..$ object:List of 2
  .. ..$ unit   : chr "documents"
  .. ..$ summary:List of 2
  ..$ user  : list()
```

I tried to use docvars().

```
c_corp %>% docvars() %>% glimpse()
```

But I get this error.

```
Error in UseMethod("docvars") : 
  no applicable method for 'docvars' applied to an object of class "c('corpus', 'character')"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please run `dput(c_corp[1:10,])` and copy the result into your question. Making an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will make solving your issue easier for others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `quanteda`, you should specify the package you want with `quanteda::docvars`.

`docvars` implementation from other packages including `readtext::docvars` does not support the data supported by `quanteda`'s `docvars`.